# VSCode Dev Containers Creating New Images

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Since early October (2022) we've noticed our dev containers in vscode are now automatically creating a new image to go with the container.  This is undesired and I'm just curious if there's the ability to turn that off.  I didn't see anything in the release notes or commits on the github that alludes to this new behavior.

Example `.devcontainer.json` :

```
{
    "name": "Focal Test",
    "image": "ubuntu:focal"
}
```

Instead of previously, where I'd end up with the `ubuntu:focal` image on my machine, now I get this image: `vsc-test-d46cd7c07849a1ba619649ef78531724-features` .  What is causing this and are there any ways to revert to the previous behavior?  It seems almost as if there was a switch under the hood to `docker-compose` by default but I see nothing in the release notes that alludes to this.

Comment: I've noticed this too and don't like it.  Appears to be from decontainer itself. https://github.com/devcontainers/cli. See the section on "decontainer up"